# Tailwind text not being aligned with image

Tags: css, tailwind-css

The text is not aligned with the photo:

```
<div class="inline-block">
    <img class="relative h-6 w-6 rounded-full bg-gray-50 ring-2 ring-white" src="https://static.generated.photos/vue-static/home/hero/6.png" alt="">
    <img class="relative bottom-2 left-4 h-3 w-3 rounded-full bg-gray-50 ring-2 ring-white" src="https://static.generated.photos/vue-static/home/hero/8.png" alt="">
</div>
Some name
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/21iaVRA65b

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `<img>` tag has moved vertically upwards but its layout box is still at its original place:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="inline-block">
    <img class="relative h-6 w-6 rounded-full bg-gray-50 ring-2 ring-white" src="https://static.generated.photos/vue-static/home/hero/6.png" alt="">
    <img class="relative left-4 h-3 w-3 rounded-full bg-gray-50 ring-2 ring-white" src="https://static.generated.photos/vue-static/home/hero/8.png" alt="">
</div>
Some name
```

You could consider using a slightly different layout method with the same visual effect but which moves the layout box:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="inline-block">
    <img class="relative h-6 w-6 rounded-full bg-gray-50 ring-2 ring-white" src="https://static.generated.photos/vue-static/home/hero/6.png" alt="">
    <img class="relative -mt-2 left-4 h-3 w-3 rounded-full bg-gray-50 ring-2 ring-white" src="https://static.generated.photos/vue-static/home/hero/8.png" alt="">
</div>
Some name
```

Edit: to have the image and the text vertically-center-aligned:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex items-center gap-1">
  <div>
      <img class="relative h-6 w-6 rounded-full bg-gray-50 ring-2 ring-white" src="https://static.generated.photos/vue-static/home/hero/6.png" alt="">
      <img class="relative -mt-2 left-4 h-3 w-3 rounded-full bg-gray-50 ring-2 ring-white" src="https://static.generated.photos/vue-static/home/hero/8.png" alt="">
  </div>
  Some name
```

Comment: That's almost what I need except "Some name" is not center aligned with the image. Any idea how I can achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Oh, you should have specified that you wanted it aligned such that the vertical mid point of the image and the text should be at the same y-position. Edited with additional solution.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Works as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

You can add parent with class `flex items-center` to make vertically center items.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex items-center gap-2">
  <div class="relative block">
      <img class="relative h-6 w-6 rounded-full bg-gray-50 ring-2 ring-white" src="https://static.generated.photos/vue-static/home/hero/6.png" alt="">
      <img class="relative bottom-2 left-4 h-3 w-3 rounded-full bg-gray-50 ring-2 ring-white" src="https://static.generated.photos/vue-static/home/hero/8.png" alt="">
  </div>
  Some name
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display: flex on the parent of inline-block div and text. Here is the example:-

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="inline-block">
      <img class="relative h-6 w-6 rounded-full bg-gray-50 ring-2 ring-white" src="https://static.generated.photos/vue-static/home/hero/6.png" alt="">
      <img class="relative bottom-2 left-4 h-3 w-3 rounded-full bg-gray-50 ring-2 ring-white" src="https://static.generated.photos/vue-static/home/hero/8.png" alt="">
  </div>
  Some name
</div>
```